# iTerm ZSH - Missing Right Prompt

Tags: terminal, iterm, zsh

I'm using oh-my-zsh and iTerm2. I've also enabled the zsh-vim-mode plugin from oh-my-zsh. One of the annoyances I've encountered is my right prompt (RPS1 & RPROMPT) doesn't seem to show up. I'd like it to indicate what vim mode I'm currently in.

I'm using the robbyrussel theme. It seems my $RPS1 variable is set. I'm wondering if there's a configuration option I'm missing.

---

<strike>I'm running 10.7.</strike>

Same issue in 10.8.

Comment: What is in your $RPS1?

Comment: Could you please attach your .zshrc?

Comment: https://github.com/jacobstr/dotfiles/tree/master/zsh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your RPROMPT in single quotes. I've seen double quotes cause issues for others with their prompts before.

I would also ditch the precmd > setprompt process for the moment and just set RPROMPT directly to simplify for testing. Start with something like

```
precmd() {
  ...
}
PROMPT=$'\n$(rb_prompt) in $(directory_name) $(git_dirty)$(need_push)\n› '
RPROMPT='%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}$(todo)%{$reset_color%}'
```

and refine from there.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating - I found a few things that fixed this:

1. I had some oh-my-zsh plugins that were setting RPS1 instead of RPROMPT - it seems that setting both caused neither to be shown.
2. Setting RPROMPT in precmd also caused it to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that $RPS1 or $RPROMPT is not defined in one of your plugins. For example, the plugin `vi-mode` defines $RPS1 inside an `if` statement. To test, disable ALL plugins inside your `.zshrc` and see if that fixes things.